# How to receive attachments from email?

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices, attachment

I would like to save attachments like `doc`, `docx` from incoming emails (maybe some other document files). I wrote a method, but it only creates files of the corresponding names and extensions on the disk, but does not write the contents to them. I connect to the server using **ews java api**. I think the problem is that the method does not see the source of the file in order to write it through the stream. Perhaps there is another working way?
Please help me correct:

```java
public class ReadMail {

    private String from;
    private String subject;
    private String date;
    public ObservableList<ReadMail> mailList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
    public ExchangeService service;
    public ReadMail() throws Exception {

        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("mail@email.local","pass");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://server-exch.email.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

        ItemView view = new ItemView (3);
        findResults = (FindItemsResults<Item>)service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

        for(Item item : findResults.getItems()){
          item.load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
          System.out.println("From: " + item.getLastModifiedName());
          System.out.println("Subject: " + item.getSubject());
          System.out.println("Date: " + item.getDateTimeReceived());
    }

    public ReadMail(String  from, String  subject, String date) {
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public ObservableList<ReadMail> mailList() throws Exception{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId());
            mailList.add(new ReadMail(message.getSender().getName(), item.getSubject(), formatter.format(message.getDateTimeReceived())));
            AttachmentCollection attachmentsCollection = message.getAttachments();
            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCollection.getCount(); i++) {
               Attachment attachment = attachmentsCollection.getPropertyAtIndex(i);
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test\\" + attachment.getName() , false);
                byte[] buffer = attachment.getName().getBytes();
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }                       
        }
        return mailList;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public String fromProperty() {
        return from;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String subjectProperty() {
        return subject;
    }
    public String getdate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setdate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: You write out the buffer, but you fill this buffer with attachment name (`attachment.getName().getBytes()`), not attachment contents. I don't have any experience with Exchange library but from what I see in Javadoc you can only get contents as `byte[]` from `FileAttachment`

Comment: @uaraven thank you so much! Apparently I needed a fresh look from the side

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

```java
public ObservableList<ReadMail> mailList() throws Exception{

        String[] attachExtensions = {".doc", ".docx"};
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

        for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {

            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId());
            mailList.add(new ReadMail(message.getSender().getName(), item.getSubject(), formatter.format(message.getDateTimeReceived())));
            AttachmentCollection attachmentsCollection = message.getAttachments();

            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCollection.getCount(); i++) {

                FileAttachment fileattaAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachmentsCollection.getPropertyAtIndex(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < attachExtensions.length; j++) {
                    if (fileattaAttachment.getName().contains(attachExtensions[i])) {
                        fileattaAttachment.load("D:\\test\\" + fileattaAttachment.getName());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Type: " + fileattaAttachment.getContentType()); 
            }                   
        }
        return mailList;
    }
```